# Convert a python script to exe file with pyinstaller that uses GuiQwt

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I would like to convert my Python script to an .exe file with pyinstaller. It creates the file, but I get error, and the .exe file doesn't work. At first I get an error that says it doesn't find a guidata/images folder, if I create it manually, then I get a new one that it doesn't find an guiqwt/images folder, but here the guiqwt exists, only the images folder not. I created that manually too, but then I still get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pupil_detect_video_v2.py", line 1531, in <module>
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
  File "pupil_detect_video_v2.py", line 232, in setupUi
    self.dialog1 = CurveDialog(edit=False, toolbar=False)
  File "guiqwt\plot.py", line 1063, in __init__
  File "guiqwt\plot.py", line 973, in __init__
  File "guiqwt\plot.py", line 1024, in create_plot
  File "guiqwt\plot.py", line 888, in __init__
  File "guiqwt\curve.py", line 1367, in __init__
  File "guiqwt\panels.py", line 85, in __init__
  File "guidata\configtools.py", line 225, in get_icon
  File "guidata\configtools.py", line 199, in get_image_file_path
RuntimeError: Image file 'item_list.png' not found
[17820] Failed to execute script 'pupil_detect_video_v2' due to unhandled exception!
```

Here is that line of my script that gives this error:

```
self.dialog1 = CurveDialog(edit=False, toolbar=False)
```

But If I run my python script it works perfectly, so the problem is not with the script. And I use an Anaconda environment if that matters.